# Tasker: Run a task when a specific bluetooth device loses connection

Tags: bluetooth, tasker

I want to run a task every time my phone loses connection to my truck's bluetooth device.

I can see a way to run a task when it connects, and obviously I can "invert" it, but inverting it doesn't sound right to me.

What is the right way to run a task upon BT connection loss to a specific device?

Comment: That's obviously the only choice you've got. I'd introduce a variable to it: BT Connected -> %MYVAR = 1. Then combine: !BT-Connected & Isset %MYVAR => just lost connection; unset %MYVAR. !BT-Connected & !Isse %MYVAR would be "lost it a while before". Just to give you a pattern to play with :)

Comment: I was looking for "Exit Tasks"

Comment: *Yuck* sure -- why didn't I think about those!?! I even use them myself...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create a profile that is active when connected to the Bluetooth device and set up an exit task to run whatever you want when the profile becomes inactive due to the device disconnects.

Comment: Ah, I see where that is now. You can create an "Exit Task" from the profiles screen... I didn't see how to do that before. Thanks

Comment: So when I connect to that specific Bluetooth device, I clear my `%PARKINGLOCATION` variable, and when the profile EXITS, then I set the `%PARKINGLOCATION` to `%LOC`, which sets the lat/long of the current location.

Comment: Here's what it will look like in your tasker profile when set up properly: https://goo.gl/cAMY4T (i added this to the answer)