# How can I get a notification when a Bluetooth device stops being accessible by my Android phone?

Tags: notifications, bluetooth, android-12, google-pixel-6

I wonder how I can get a notification when a Bluetooth device stops being accessible by my Android phone. I use Pixel 6 + Android 12.

Example of list of Bluetooth devices that are accessible by my Android phone:

[image]

When a given device (e.g., "TV")  disappears from the list, I'd like to receive a notification.

Comment: You'll notice when a *connected* device is no longer available. To have notification for devices that were in range and no longer are isn't possible. There never was a provision for such event. Just imagine the nightmare it would be if it happened for each device you come in contact briefly in any given day.

Comment: @ChanganAuto thanks, in my case, I'm just looking for a way to get notified for just a single Bluetooth device (not all Bluetooth device).

Comment: @ChanganAuto it is possible to create an app which can periodically scan nearby Bluetooth devices or only user-defined Bluetooth devices, and alert the user if a device is longer available since the last periodic scan. See docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/find-bluetooth-devices

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Tasker has [BT_NEAR](https://tasker.joaoapps.com/userguide/en/help/sh_bt_near.html) profile/trigger option. If you have Tasker already or if you can give it a go to its [trial version](https://tasker.joaoapps.com/download.html) than that profile/trigger might solve the problem for you. You'll have to adjust the timings at which to run a periodic scan, and than as an action for that profile you can setup a simple notification as an event reminder.

Comment: @Firelord Yes, you can program almost anything in software.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using Android App  **Tasker**.
Here is a link: [Tasker: Run a task when a specific bluetooth device loses connection](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37837/tasker-run-a-task-when-a-specific-bluetooth-device-loses-connection)

Note: If you haven't used Tasker before, it is powerful, but it has a pretty steep learning curve.

Comment: Hi. OP's question is about whether a given BT device is within discoverable range or not (that's what Available Devices list shows us). If it is not within discoverable range at any point in time than OP should be notified. The linked Q&A does not help with that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).